# Casting cassandra timestamp column as timeuuid

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, timeuuid

I'm getting events from `Kafka` and storing into `Cassandra`. Parsing `json` which contains fields `eventID, sessionID, timestamp, userID` to create columns for `Cassandra` table which looks like this:

```
cassandra@cqlsh> CREATE TABLE mydata.events (
   ...     "event_date" date,
   ...     "eventID" text,
   ...     "userID" text,
   ...     timestamp timeuuid,
   ...     "sessionID" text,
   ...     "fullJson" text,
   ...     PRIMARY KEY ("event_date", timestamp, "sessionID")
```

and in code:

```
case class cassandraFormat(
                       eventID: String, 
                       sessionID: String,
                       timeuuid: UUID, // timestamp as timeuuid
                       userID: String,
                       event_date: LocalDate, // YYYY-MM-dd format
                       fullJson: String // full json from Kafka
                     )
```

I need to add `timestamp` column as `timeuuid`. Since I'm parsing from `json`, extracted all values from header and created columns in this fashion:

```
 val allJson = rdd.
            map(x => {
              implicit val formats: DefaultFormats.type = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
              //use serialization default to format a Map to JSON
              (x, Serialization.write(x))
            }).
            filter(x => x._1 isDefinedAt "header").
            map(x => (x._1("header"), x._2)).
            filter(x => (x._1 isDefinedAt "userID") &&
              (x._1 isDefinedAt "eventID") &&
              (x._1 isDefinedAt "sessionID") &&
              (x._1 isDefinedAt "timestamp").
            map(x => cassFormat(x._1("eventID").toString,
              x._1("sessionID").toString,
              com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs.startOf(x._1("timestamp").toString.toLong),
              x._1("userID").toString,
              com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate.fromMillisSinceEpoch(x._1("timestamp").toString.toLong),
              x._2))
```

This part:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs.startOf(x._1("timestamp").toString.toLong)
```

is generating Error

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "2019-05-09T09:00:52.553+0000"    at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Even tried: 
           `java.util.UUID.fromString(x._1("timestamp").toString`,
also generating same Error. 
How to properly cast/convert `timestamp` as `timeuuid` and insert into `Cassandra` via spark job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it, converting `timestamp` format to `dateTime` and to `millis`, then generate `uuid`:

```
val dateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimePattern)

val allJson = rdd.
              map(x => {
                implicit val formats: DefaultFormats.type = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
                //use serialization default to format a Map to JSON
                (x, Serialization.write(x))
              }).
              filter(x => x._1 isDefinedAt "header").
              map(x => (x._1("header"), x._2)).
              filter(x => (x._1 isDefinedAt "userID") &&
                (x._1 isDefinedAt "eventID") &&
                (x._1 isDefinedAt "sessionID") &&
                (x._1 isDefinedAt "timestamp").
              map(x => {
                var millis: Long  = System.currentTimeMillis() // if timestamp format is invalid, put current timestamp instead
                try {
                  val dateStr: String = x._1("timestamp").asInstanceOf[String]
                  // timestamp from event json
                  // create DateTime from Timestamp string
                  val dateTime: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, dateFormatter)
                  // create millis from DateTime
                  millis = dateTime.toInstant.toEpochMilli
                } catch {
                  case e: Exception =>
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                // generate timeuuid
                val uuid = new UUID(UUIDs.startOf(millis).getMostSignificantBits, random.nextLong)
                // generate eventDate
                val eventDate = com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate.fromMillisSinceEpoch(millis)
                cassFormat(x._1("eventID").toString,
                  x._1("sessionID").toString,
                  uuid,
                  x._1("userID").toString,
                  eventDate,
                  x._2)
              })
            allJson.saveToCassandra(CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE_NAME, CASSANDRA_EVENTS_TABLE)
        }
      })
```

`timestamp` column in cassandra now looks like: `58976340-7313-11e9-910d-60dce7513b94`

Answer (score 2):

I've solved that problem with UDF.

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
 
val toTimeuuid: java.sql.Timestamp => String = x => UUIDs.startOf(x.getTime()).toString()
val fromTimeuuid: String => java.sql.Timestamp = x => new java.sql.Timestamp(UUIDs.unixTimestamp(java.util.UUID.fromString(x)))
 
val toTimeuuidUDF = udf(toTimeuuid)
val fromTimeuuidUDF = udf(fromTimeuuid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a string that is not a number and you are trying to convert it into one using `toLong`. thus the exception.

Looking at [this](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/UUIDGen.java), it looks like you can get a UUID based on some timestamp using this method:

```
public static UUID getTimeUUID(long when)
```

You are gonna have to parse the string into a `DateTime` or an `Instant` then pass the milliseconds of that DateTime/ Instant to `getTimeUUID`

Comment: I know from error that this string cant be converted to Long.. question is how to do it with datastax driver in Scala/Spark application?